# <a> links simply not working/not clickable

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have some images in the footer, wrapped in  tags. For some reason they are not working whatsoever... I am totally lost.
website is [HERE](http://new-wave-academy.com/)
any help would be great (footer is on every single page on the site)

relevant html:

```
<div class="socialLinks">
  <div class="footerTitle">Follow Us At</div>
  <div class="iconsContainer">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/NewWaveAcademyMMA/">
    <img class="socialicon" src="../images/fb.svg">
  </a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/NewWaveMMA?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor">
    <img class="socialicon" src="../images/twit.svg">
  </a>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/newwaveacademymma/">
    <img class="socialicon" src="../images/insta.svg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links on your webpage are working. You are unable to click on the links because you have placed a div over your links. Actually, you are clicking this div, not the links. This is the div (look it up in the browser console):

```
<div class="footercopyright">Copyright, All Rights Reserved NWA 2018</div>
```

You may resolve this by either removing this div, or by setting a higher `z-index` for the links container.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.footercopyright div` is overlapping the rest of your footer.

Since you're using floats to align the `.affiliations` and `.sociallinks` divs, you should wrap them in a clearfix. This will clear your floats and prevent your copyright div from expanding to fill the space.

```
<div class="footerbox">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="affiliations"></div>
    <div class="socialLinks"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footercopyright"></div>
<div>

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add clear in below class and work.
Also, noticed small dotted below links::

You use `display:inline-block;` on `<a>` to remove this

```
`.footercopyright {
    position: relative;
    color: #232528;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    clear: both;
}`
```